# how to setup wal directory location when initialising postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I want to separate my `pg_wal` directory location from the default `data` directory in postgres. I can set the `PGDATA` variable to setup my `data` directory location but not sure how to setup my `pg_wal` directory?

Any pointers would be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no environment variable for this.

Shutdown the database instance, move the directory, then create a symlink (or whatever it is called on your OS) at the old location linking to the new location.

Or create the server with the `--waldir=/what/ever/pg_wal` option to 'initdb', which will do the same thing as above for you.

Comment: do you have the full command: `--waldir=/what/ever/pg_wal` ?? @jjanes

Comment: Sorry, that is an argument to the`initdb` command.  I don't know what other arguments you might need for it though.

Comment: I have tried this argument at `initdb` stage but it fails. I think I will just have to try and hack this and move the `wal` directory to the secondary disk manually

Comment: What error did it fail with?